# How to Start itemCount in ListView.builder from where previous list left off?

Tags: flutter, listview, count, range

I have 2 rows of Listview builders (scrollable horizontally) showing interests.

Hoping that the first row will show the first 6 interests, and the next row showing the rest on the list.

How do I make the itemCount in the second as a range from 7 all the way to the end?

Any help is appreciated. The snippet of the code is as follows:

```
Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(6, 6, 0, 0),
                      child: Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.045,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
                            itemCount: 6,
                            itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                              return Interests2(AvailableInterestChosen(
                                allInterests[index],
                                isChosen: false,
                              ));
                            }),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(6, 3, 0, 0),
                      child: Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.045,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
                            **// itemCount: allInterests range from 6 to end of list,**
                            itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                              return Interests2(AvailableInterestChosen(
                                allInterests[index],
                                isChosen: false,
                              ));
                            }),
                      ),
                    ),
...
```

The bold part in the 2nd padding is where I'm having trouble building the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call your second list view in listview.builder like that

```
ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
                           
                            itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                              return Interests2(AvailableInterestChosen(
                                allInterests[6+index],
                                isChosen: false,
                              ));
```

Comment: Happy to help you!

Comment: by any chance, do you know how to solve this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67705273/build-data-back-to-listview-builder-flutter

Answer (score 1):

As parameters for second List view, you can use allInterests.size()-6 for item count, and index + 6 for access index to allInterests list.

Answer (score 1):

second part:

```
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(6, 3, 0, 0),
                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.045,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
                        **// itemCount: allInterests range from 6 to end of list,**
                        itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                          int newIndex = index + 6;
                          return Interests2(AvailableInterestChosen(
                            allInterests[newIndex],
                            isChosen: false,
                          ));
                        }),
                        itemCount: allInterests.length - 6
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: Thank you Jim for your reply! I gave the answer to Anushka even tho you replied earlier. Bcos Anushka had a cleaner answer, and also to motivate him/her to contribute more. ^^ she has 100 pts to your almost 3000. Hope you understand thanks!

Comment: no worries~ it's your call! may be a little up vote will help?~ LOL

Comment: definitely, but I need at least 15 reputation pts to upvote. Lmao, will upvote when I have it !

Comment: Hey Jim, by any chance, you know how to solve this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67705273/build-data-back-to-listview-builder-flutter